# C# Adding Generic List to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, generics

So I'm running into a problem with generic lists in C# such that:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<long, List<object>>();
foo.Add(123, new List<string>());
```

Gives the error: `Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to System.Collections.Generic.List<object>`

Where as this works fine:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<long, object>();
foo.Add(123, new string());
```

My real use case would look like this:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<long, List<ISomeInterface>>();
foo.Add(123, new List<SomeClassA>());
foo.Add(345, new List<SomeClassB>());
```

Where both SomeClassA and SomeClassB implement ISomeInterface.  Is this possible?

The idea being I can grab a list of ISomeInterface from the dictionary and iterate the list calling SomeMethod that is defined on ISomeInterface.

Comment: What you want is covariance and that is only available with interfaces.  So `Dictionary<long, IEnumerable<object>>` would work, but of course you then can only take items out of values of the dictionary, but that's to make sure you don't put a string into what is actually a list of int.

Comment: Not sure if this would help in your case, but you can declare a list of type `List<ISomeInterface>` and populate it with instances of `SomeObject`, and then add it to the `Dictionary`

Comment: If you need to know the concrete type of an interface that's a code smell.  You should push any class type logic like that into the classes via the interface's API.

Comment: What @juharr said is correct, but you could also use `Dictionary<long, IReadOnlyList<ISomeInterface>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ToList` for casting the class to the generic type interface as in

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<int, List<ISomething>> dictionary
                = new Dictionary<int, List<ISomething>>();

            var list = new List<Something>() { new Something() };
            dictionary.Add(1, list.ToList<ISomething>());
        }

        public interface ISomething
        {
        }

        public class Something : ISomething
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  `ToList<ISomething>()` while perhaps obvious to some, was exactly what I needed and the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

For your real use case:

You need to declare your list as `List<ISomeInterface>` and then fill it with objects that implement such interface.

```
var foo = new Dictionary<long, List<ISomeInterface>>();
foo.Add(123, new List<ISomeInterface>());
foo[123].Add(new SomeObjectThatImplementsISomeInterface());
```

Other way would be to create the list first, then add it to the dictionary.

```
var bar = new List<ISomeInterface>();
bar.add(new SomeObjectThatImplementsISomeInterface());
bar.add(new SomeOtherObjectThatImplementsISomeInterface());
var foo = new Dictionary<long, List<ISomeInterface>>();
foo.Add(123, bar);
```

Of course when you get back values from `foo` you'll get them as `ISomeInterface`, and will need reflection if you need to know the specific type of such object.

Comment: reflection or just `.Cast<>()`

Comment: @r1verside Better yet is to push that type of logic into the classes via the interface API so you don't need reflection or casting.

Comment: @r1verside what I understood in OP's comments is that he needs to know the type. If he knows or expects a specific one he can cast it but as juharr mentions that's not realley what interfaces are for.

Comment: I need to know the Interface type so I can call the shared methods when I iterate the list.  This answer seems best with one change, instead of `foo[123].Add()` do `foo[123].AddRange()`

Comment: @Shane if you already have the list, then just add it to the dictionary instead of creating then populating it. I'll update my answer on that.

Comment: @Josh, your original answer put me on the right path, I'll update my question to be more explicit as your second part is a little different use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around it with System.Linq:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<long, List<object>>();
foo.Add(123, new List<string>().ToList<object>());
```

similarly,

```
var foo = new Dictionary<long, List<ISomeInterface>>();
foo.Add(123, new List<SomeObject>().ToList<ISomeInterface>());
```

another possibility:

```
foo.Add(123, new List<ISomeInterface>(new List<SomeObject>()));
```